# Can't retractall()?

Tags: prolog

I have :

```
 :- dynamic blah/2.
 retractall(blah(_,_)).
```

But I still get :

```
No permission to modify static procedure `retractall/1'
```

How can I delete all occurrence of blah() ?
BTW it works in swipl console !!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The predicate `retractall/1` is a standard **built-in** predicate and as such, in most systems, cannot be redefined by the user. In your code you're trying to define a fact for this predicate, hence the error message. But on a console you're using it as a *goal*, i.e. you're simply calling the built-in predicate.

If you want to ensure that there are no clauses for the `blah/2` predicate when you load your source file, then use instead the `initialization/1` standard directive:

```
:- initialization(retractall(blah(_, _))).
```

Comment: thanks. Does not work for me because it seems initialization() is called after the file has been loaded. I want the opposite i.e. call it before sourcing the file so that it can clean-up the current state (blah()'s). I need this mainly for swipl testing, rather than running program. I'm also getting : "Syntax error: Operator priority clash" !! thanks again

Comment: @CapelliC Thanks. Fixed.